# Magento2 : How to remove product attribute for new attribute set using installation script

Tags: magento2

How to remove the existing product attribute with newly created product attribute set using InstallSchema or UpgradeSchema in Magento2.

I have created one **attribute set** "My Custm" now I want to remove the **country_of_manufacture** attribute from my "My Custm" set.

Comment: you want to remove product attribute using installData.php file right?

Comment: @JigsParmar, yes for particular Attribute Set, not for Default attribute set

Comment: @JigsParmar have u got my issue?

Comment: you just want to remove from particular attirbute set, you can do it from admin

Comment: I want to do it script only.

Comment: using installation script i want to make it work